# Решение задачи на Lisp c использованием функционалов

Tags: lisp

Даны два множества, представленных списками:
     (a1 a2 … aN)
     (b1 b2 … bМ).
Написать функцию, возвращающую декартово произведение двух множеств:
     ((a1 b1)  (a1 b2) … (а1 bM) (a2 b1) (a2 b2) … (a2 bM) …  (aN bM))
Использовав функционалы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    (defun decart(lst1 lst2)
(let ((newlist nil) (oldlist lst1))
(loop
    (cond ((eql oldlist nil) (return newlist)))
    (if (eql newlist nil)
        (setq newlist (mapcar (lambda (a) (list (car oldlist) a)) lst2))
        (setq newlist (append newlist 
            (mapcar (lambda (a) (list (car oldlist) a)) lst2)))
    )
    (setq oldlist (cdr oldlist))
)))
```

Comment: не идеально, но работает